# how to use spark map with .net for spark

Tags: .net, apache-spark, dictionary

how to use spark map with .net for spark?
like in python:

```
nums=sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
squared=nums.map(lambda x: x*x).collect);
```

in scale:

```
val input=sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4])
val res=input.map(x=>x*x)
```

but .net dataframe doesn't has a funtion named map

this document(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.spark.sql.functions.map?view=spark-dotnet) hasn't demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `map` function belongs to the RDD API, while the .Net implements the Dataframe API (aka Spark SQL). You need to use correct functions, like, `Select` to transform data.  So, if you get your data into the dataframe `df`, then you can do something like in your `map` with `df.Select(df["col"]*df["col"])`, etc.

See the [examples](https://github.com/dotnet/spark#samples) in the Spark.Net repo.